# Converting a UIImage into a cv::Mat and reading the cv::Mat from file gives different results

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opencv, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm using the following code to convert a `UIImage` into a `cv::Mat`:

```
-(cv::Mat)openCVMat{

    // Turn a UIImage into a cv::Mat
    // Draw the image into a bitmap context: the Mat's matrix


    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage);
    CGFloat columns = self.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = self.size.height;

    cv::Mat m(rows, columns, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));      // (bits, 4 channels (RGBA)


    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(m.data,
                                                 columns,
                                                 rows,
                                                 8,
                                                 m.step[0],
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

    // Draw
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, columns, rows), self.CGImage);



    // Cleanup
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Return
    return m;

}
```

It seems to work fine, but on some images the resulting `cv::Mat` is different if I just read it from file with `imread`:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"blue"
                                         withExtension:@"png"];
cv::Mat fromFile = cv::imread([url.path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::Mat withAlpha;
cv::cvtColor(fromFile, withAlpha, CV_BGRA2RGBA);
```

In this case, the resulting `cv::Mat` (withAlpha) is slightly different, specially in the corner of the images.

For example, when reading the image as a `UIImage` and then converting to `cv::Mat`, the final pixel is:
[0,0,110,255]   this is RGBA

while the last pixel after reading it directly with imread is:
[0,0,255, 110]  also RGBA

To make things better, this doesn't happen with all images.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's the test image: [blue.png](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3978473/stackOverflow/blue.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's some mismatch between the format being read and format with which the cv::Mat is being created.

I see that while loading the image from the resource bundle, you're using:

```
           CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR.
```

Just keep CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED and check. That should guarantee the loading of the alpha channel from your PNG. 
See if that helps.

Comment: Nope, same result. :-P

Comment: How are you getting the pixel values? Are you using Vec4b ?